# How to find out all the unique hours in between 2 pandas timestamps?

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say there are two timestamp objects in python like as following:
`2016-12-23 22:00:00` and `2016-12-24 02:00:00`
How to find out all the unique hours in between these 2 timestamps, inclusive of the lower value but exclusive of the upper value, such that the desired result be in the form of a list as shown:

`allhrs = [2016-12-23 22:00:00, 2016-12-23 23:00:00, 2016-12-24 00:00:00, 2016-12-24 01:00:00]`

What is the most pythonic way to do this? Any help appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.date_range`:

```
allhrs = pd.date_range('2016-12-23 22:00:00', '2016-12-24 02:00:00', freq='H', closed='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

Without Pandas:

```
import datetime
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
start = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-12-23 22:00:00', fmt)            
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-12-24 02:00:00', fmt)              
t = start.replace(minute=0,second=0)
if t < start:
   t += datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

hours_list = []
while t < end:
   hours_list.append(t.strftime(fmt))
   t += datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

print(hours_list)
```